# Best 'free' option for alert notifications other than email/SMS

Tags: linux, scripting, alerts

Looking for a Linux script solution that can send alerts to a service such as Twitter, Skype or Google Talk and sends to Android and iPhone clients.

Have found twurl for Twitter with previous Bash scripts using curl no longer supported. But twurl looks promising. But haven't seen how to get Android Twitter client to make a distinctive sound when a tweet arrives.

Found some info about Skype4Py from several years ago that supports Skype Chats. But doesn't look like it is currently supported.

Have tried a few CLI clients for XMPP/Google Talk including xmpp4r-simple and freetalk, but found xmpp4r-simple buggy and freetalk succeeded in sending one chat message, but most never arrived.

Whatever is used needs to support Android and iPhone clients. Reason why email is problematic is that Gmail gets very upset when emails start flooding in every minute as a result of alerts.

Any suggestions?

Comment: So it sounds like you've already found a solution that will send alerts to twitter...but you're unhappy with your Android twitter client.  Is that correct?

Answer (score 2):

We use sendxmpp (http://sendxmpp.platon.sk/) as a command line XMPP client to send alerts to our Jabber accounts, and Jabiru as a Android client : works great !

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for basic authorization compatibility with older apps (like the ones you mentioned) try http://supertweet.net

I use it with a PHP script I wrote pre-oAuth.